# Less css - Can we use more variables seperate with coma

Tags: css, variables, less

Like this

```
@ShuttleGrey:  #606369;
```

I need same output color value from  more variables [I am looking for a single line solution]

```
@themeOne:, @themeTwo:, @themeThree:             @ShuttleGrey;
```

I know my code is an error , Does anyone know to fix this situation ?

Thanks

Comment: Study this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Do you need to apply the same color value to many components?

Comment: @Shibin Ragh,  would you please accept an answer or just flag user2072923 's answer, he just copied everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want the same properties to apply in many places you can do something like this

```
.aProperty{
  color:#606369
 }
```

Then you can do something like this to add the same properties to other elements

```
 .anotherProperty{
   background:#000; //just like that
   .aProperty;
  }
```

This way `.anotherProperty` will inherit the properties of  `aProperty`.
This way you can even add other properties and use them at many places.

Answer (score -1):

```
 .aProperty{
  color:#606369
  }
```

Then you can do something like this to add the same properties to other elements

```
.anotherProperty{
 background:#000; //just like that
 .aProperty;
 }
```

Since  no answer is accepted I am trying my luck:)

Comment: copying answers does not help